Sphinx + rst2pdf python variables from conf.py
Trying to use sphinx #Version in a rst2pdf yml style to add it to each page of the pdf.
# conf.py
version = str(datetime.date.today())

rst_epilog = """
.. |ProjectVersion| replace:: versione del  {versionnum}
""".format(
    versionnum=version,
)

with a test.rst it works:
# test.rst


|ProjectVersion|

Instead if I add it to style.yml it is ignored, blank space is shown in pdf:
pageTemplates:
  decoratedPage:
    defaultFooter: |
      .. class:: right

       pag. ###Page### di ###Total###

      .. class:: draft

         Versione del 4 luglio 2024       |ProjectVersion|

    defaultHeader: &draftCentered |

      .. class:: draft

           ###Section###

  mainPage: &draftTopAndBottom
    defaultFooter: *draftCentered
    defaultHeader: *draftCentered
    showFooter: true
    showHeader: true

  mainPage: &noheader
    defaultFooter: *draftCentered
    defaultHeader: *draftCentered
    showFooter: false
    showHeader: false

  coverPage: *noheader

  emptyPage: *draftTopAndBottom

styles:
  draft: { alignment: center, parent: bodytext, fontName: fontSansBold }

Looked at

rst2pdf manual
how to access sphinx variables
custom style on pdf

but cannot find anyting related to this use case, if I insert ###Page### it works, can you please tell me if the version defined in conf.py can be available in rst2pdf?
